# Reordering categories in stacked bar chart based on count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a stacked bar chart in ggplot2 where the bars in the stack are ordered according to the count of that category. When I attempt this using the below code, it appears that ggplot2 arranges the order of the bars in the stacked plot according to alphabetical order. Other answers on Stackoverflow suggest that ggplot2 order the bars according to the order in which R consumes the data, however in the 'a' dataframe, the appliance column is in the order of 'Radio', 'Laptop', 'TV' 'Fridge' (the first 4 rows) which isn't how it is shown in the graph either.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(tidyr)

 #some data 
 SalesData<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), ThisYear=c(5,25,5,8), LastYear=c(6,20,5,8))

 #transform the data into 'long format' for ggplot2
 a<- gather(SalesData, Sales, Total, ThisYear, LastYear)

 #Produce the bar chart
 p<-ggplot(a, aes(fill=Appliance, y=Total, x=Sales)) + 
 geom_bar( stat="identity")
 p
```

What I want to happen is for the largest counts to be at the bottom of the graph, so I need a way to order the data in this way. So in this example it would be 'Laptop' at the bottom, then 'Fridge', 'Radio' and 'TV' and for the legend to match this order.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geom_bar uses factors to create the stacks. You can see the levels present in your data with `factor(a$Appliance)`. By default, these levels are sorted on alphabetic order. However, you can manually set the order of the levels as follows:

```
a$Appliance = factor(a$Appliance, levels=c("TV", "Radio", "Fridge", "Laptop"))
```

If you do this before creating your ggplot, you will have your desired order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorder the factor levels before you plot the stacked bar chart. For this, there are several possibilities:

#### With base R

```
order_appliance <- unique(a$Appliance[order(a$Total)])
a$Appliance <- factor(a$Appliance, levels = order_appliance)
```

#### With dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
a <- a %>% 
  arrange(Total) %>% 
  mutate(Appliance = factor(Appliance, levels = unique(Appliance)))
```

#### With forcats

```
library(forcats)
a$Appliance <- fct_reorder(a$Appliance, a$Total)

For the plot you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`: 

ggplot(a, aes(fill = Appliance, y = Total, x = Sales)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could re-order factors based on sum, then plot, see example:

```
# reorder labels based on row sums
myFac <- SalesData$Appliance[ order(rowSums(SalesData[, 2:3])) ]

# wide-to-long, then reorder factor
a <- gather(SalesData, Sales, Total, ThisYear, LastYear) %>% 
  mutate(Appliance = factor(Appliance, labels = myFac, levels = myFac ))

# then plot
ggplot(a, aes(fill = Appliance, y = Total, x = Sales)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: @Basil Avoid "thank you" comments, if helpful upvote/accept as answer, read about [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, accepted answer is manual approach, mine and kath's answer gets the order of factors based on data.